# Programmatic access to company files

Tags: postgresql, file, filesystems, shared-directory

I am developing a fairly large web application for my company, part of which will allow employees to reply, via generated email, to customer queries related to specific products. Each product is connected to a certain set of files (PDFs) which must always be attached to the email and it is important to note that these files are regularly updated. This of course means that the application will be accessing the same files as the people.

My problem is the following: How can the application manage and read these files in a reliable way, without impacting usability when accessed directly and without being affected by, for example, a file name change?

I was thinking of just having a service scan the entire directory (and its subdirectories recursively) in a loop(like every 10 minutes or so) and update a database table with file paths and so on, but this seems like a very fragile and inflexible solution.

Is it generally not recommended to have an application access files that humans can access as well? Should I make a copy of all files and update manually? Hardly seems practical...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The main problem, is the "free" files access from users. I think you need to use a DMS Before ([Document management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system))!

Comment: Thank you, I can look into that. Can you recommend any DMSs?

Comment: Honestly, i dont actually use one, but in the past i choosed [alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) , it was free, open source, but should look by your self, depending what you really want